# Bind JSONArray to adapter

Tags: android

How would you go about to bind a `JSONArray` to an adapter, the adapter will be used to bind data to a spinner.

Of course I could iterate over the strings in the `JSONArray` and add 'em to a String array, but that seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own adapter class, extending `BaseAdapter`, that adapts your JSON data according to whatever rules you feel are appropriate. The built-in adapter classes are not well-suited for JSON data.

Comment: I have not looked at how the BaseAdapter is implemented, but would there be difference in extending baseadapter or parse the JSONArray to an array of strings?

Comment: Well, you don't wind up with multiple copies of your data (one in the JSONArray, one in your string array).

Comment: Well that's of course true, I guess you have to think 'bout these things when you are developing for smaller devices. I just have to figure out what methods to override in the BaseAdapter class.

Comment: You'll see some custom adapters here: http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-adapter http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-sacklist http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge -- These are more for modifying existing adapter data in a composite pattern, but they may still be useful examples.